# Express.js timeouts requests to static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, node.js-connect

I've been struggling with this for weeks now - for some reason, Express works fine for few hours after launching, then it starts ignoring the requests for static files.
It looks something like this:

```
GET / 304 153ms
GET /js/bootstrap.min.js 200 120000ms
GET /img/guide/0.png 200 120000ms
GET /img/guide/1.png 200 120000ms
GET /img/guide/2.png 200 120000ms
```

As I look into Chrome's resource browser, the page at /, handled by a normal app.get() function, is working normally and sent to the client - static files aren't.

From the side of a client, the page loads for 2 minutes showing blank white nothingness, then shows the content without any CSS styling or scripts (predictable).

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, even simplest examples of Express I've found have this problem, and I didn't see it posted anywhere. Maybe it's the order of middleware, I seriously don't even know anymore...

I hope it's something trivial, and I'm just stupid/blind; here's a part of the code:

```
app = express()
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.set('view engine', 'jade')
app.use(express.logger('dev'))
app.use(express.cookieParser())
app.use(express.bodyParser())
app.use(express.session({
    key: 'express.sid',
    secret: 'wewillchangethislater',
    store: sessionStore
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.isAjax = false
    res.locals.user = req.user
    next()
})
app.use(app.router)
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
```

I've seen it happening with much simpler code tho too:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.set('view engine', 'jade')
app.use(express.logger('dev'))
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.isAjax = false
    next()
})
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

*some routes here*

app.listen(9999)
```

The rest of the code is in this utterly broken repo: https://github.com/Maxorq/Mikuia/blob/master/www.js
The only thing I found to help in those cases is restarting, which isn't too fun :/

Answer (score -1):

I've seen this behavior with resin server due to configuration

Maybe not the same but might point you in the right direction

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325309/css-and-js-files-hold-the-http-connection-until-timeout-on-resin-4